# groovy exception: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to load template:sample.template

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I have sample.template as follows:

`xmlDeclaration()
cars {
    cars.each {
        car(make: it.make, model: it.model)
    }
}`

and I have my sample class that

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration();
        MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config);
        Template template = engine.createTemplateByPath("sample.template");
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        Writable output = template.make(model);
        print(output)
    }`

and I get exception: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to load template:sample.template....

I have kept this file in the same folder as of my class, tried putting it in resources folder but the error persists.

Where to keep these files and how to access it? (I am using IntelliJ idea)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you put the template in resources

And assuming your class is called `Sample`

Change

```
Template template = engine.createTemplateByPath("sample.template");
```

To

```
Template template = engine.createTemplate(Sample.class.getResource("/sample.template"));
```

Comment: I just wanted to confirm this is the correct answer, if you came to this thread attempting to get the MarkupTemplateEngine example to work in the official groovy-lang docs, and are new to JVM based languages (such as myself). I believe the concept you are looking for is called "resource files". That should get you sorted out. Cheers!